# What is StackOOM?

Tags: discussion

While googling some error message I came across https://stackoom.com/ which seems like just a Chinese ripoff of Stack Overflow:

[image]

However upon closer inspection of the [most-upvoted questions](https://stackoom.com/index?tab=Votes) it seems like those are just *the most-upvoted Stack Overflow questions, either translated automatically or by hand*, plus there doesn't seem to be a way to sign up or post anything, and the main page seems to not have been updated since 2021-02-22.

I'm taking the name to mean StackOOM = Stack Out Of Memory.

There's a big red ad at the top saying "500,000 annual salary tutorial download" which links to https://www.javaxxz.com/, which is a site with programming tutorial videos which seem hidden behind a paywall (VIP membership).

Does anyone know anything about this site or who is behind it? Additionally, is this legal as [Stack Overflow contributions are licensed as Creative Commons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/12528/259308), or is it illegal because of the (presumed) trademark infringement?

Comment: I'm unsure if it's nefarious, hence the question

Comment: They don't have adequate attribution, specifically they fail on the: *"Hyperlink each author name directly back to their user profile page on the source site"* front, so feel free to report them

Comment: You should report the site, as it's against the attribution front. As for the site, it's yet another one of those sites which clone Stack Overflow.

Comment: StackOOM is now using StackOverflow's favicon, which is causing some problems as I skim through search results. I click SO links because they're useful, and this nonsense site (which, I'm fairly confident, is not correctly attributing the answers anyway, and which definitely doesn't have the right to use SO's logos) keeps tripping me up.

Comment: Hope you don't mind I cited you in my [follow-up question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426382/6574038) @SilvioMayolo .